# how to resize words in textbox?

Tags: html, css

I resized this(id = box1) input textbox but encountered a problem. Initially the textbox resized but later, when i wrote words in it ,it appeared as if not resized.

html:

```
<div  id="username">
  <form>
    <p>
      <span>UserName:</span>
      <input name="UserName" type="text" size="0" id="box1"   >
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

css :

```
#username{
position:fixed;
top: 23px;
left: 709px;
right: 10%;
width: 280px;
height: 61px;
font-family: corbel;
border:medium;
border-color:black;
}
```

Comment: Try the `font-size` css property.

Comment: it changed but i need to position it

Comment: try the `padding` css property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target your input and set a font-size using CSS:

```
#box1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

You can check this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JRKyte/pen/Akujq/) out to see a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer: http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Use "vw'.

And remember that people won't resize their window. They will load their window in a fixed dimension and there is in some cases landscape and portrait mode. But people won't go re-sizing their screens. 
It's something you and I do as web-developers to test our shizzle on the screen.

I am using "vw" and it works like a charm.

You can also use fittext.js ---> http://fittextjs.com/
I don't recommend it since you can use "vw", but hey the option is there for you to choose from.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
font-size: 20pt;
```

for example